# Should the unit tests be independent of the implementations

Tags: unit-testing

In the book- [The Art of Unit Testing](https://www.manning.com/books/the-art-of-unit-testing-third-edition), I have read that the changes to the code base should not change the unit tests. But I have a hard time figuring out what should not be changed in the unit tests. Is it the behavior being tested or the code in the unit test? For me, changes to the test project code seems inevitable. As an example:

```
public interface IGreetingService
{
    void ShowGreeting();
}

public class ConsoleGreetingService : IGreetingService
{
    public void ShowGreeting()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
    }
}

public class MsgBoxGreetingService : IGreetingService
{
    public void ShowGreeting()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello!");
    }
}
```

If we already have unit tests in place for the `ConsoleGreetingService`, we have to do some changes to the unit tests when we change our implementation of `IGreetingservice` to the `MsgBoxGreetingService`. It might be a simple change in the test code like changing the initialization of the `ConsoleGreetingService` object to `MsgBoxGreetingService`. But still, is that not considered a change in test or are changes like that considered "acceptable"? Then it seems like unit tests are not completely independent of the implementation code.

Comment: If tested behaviour changes, then tests change, yes. That is why unit tests tend to decouple the unit/system under test/SUT being tested from its dependencies. A unit test for "SUT shows a greeting" would likely inject a MockGreetingService to conduct the test. But an integration test "greeting messages are shown via the console" based on the default dependency configuration would change when you want it to demonstrate "greeting messages are shown via GUI".

Comment: A good question, but I am downvoting because the **example is terrible.**  Methods that do IO are notoriously lousy for Unit Tests, and, as @Doc Brown notes, tests of those arguably aren't even Unit Tests.

Comment: @user949300 don't downvote for bad examples, write an answer saying why OP's problem includes that the examples are bad

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I have read that the changes to the code base should not change the unit tests.

Close, but no. Lets fix that:

Changes to the *implementation choices*, ones that change neither the behavior nor the API it's being tested through, should not change the unit tests.

There are many implementation choices that must be made in any codebase that can be changed without forcing changes to well designed unit tests. There's a whole book that talks about such choices. [Refactoring by Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/books/refactoring.html).

A well designed unit test requires the code to exhibit a behavior and provide an API through which to elicit that behavior. Change either one and you break the unit test. But preserve that and the codebase is free to change as you like. Doing that is what Fowler called refactoring.

Your example code spectacularly fails to be unit testable code precisely because you provided no such API. This code is only testable with integration tests or obnoxious mocking.

A unit test should enforce expected behavior. The "behavior" code here is simply a hard coded string. One that is defined in multiple places. Sending that string to a console, a GUI or a print out is not a behavior. That's just a destination.

Writing unit testable code requires designing the code to be unit tested. A classic pattern for that is imperative shell, functional [core](https://kennethlange.com/functional-core-imperative-shell/). This pattern lets you push all the non-functional code away from your behavior code which will live in easily testable functional code that will provide that needed API.

This all boils down to writing code that does whatever logic to figure out what the greeting will be and unit testing that logic without knowing or caring where the greeting will go. Because that's IO. IO should not be part of the unit of a unit test. Push that out to the imperative shell. If you must test that (many don't) don't test it with a unit test.

Answer (score 9):

> I have read that the changes to the code base should not change the unit tests.

Let me say this straight: **this makes no sense**.

I don't have that book at hand, and you did not tell us which section lead you to this interpretation, still I am convinced you must have misread something. Unit tests (as well as any other kind of test) will not be required to change when an implementation of a certain (externally visible) behaviour changes, **as long as the desired behaviour itself stays the same**. But when the implementation changes up to the point where the desired behaviour changes, then the tests for this behaviour obviously have to change as well.

For example, different implementations of `ConsoleGreetingService.ShowGreeting` like

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
```

or

```
const string greetings = "Hello!";
Console.WriteLine(greetings);
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine(GetHelloInCertainLanguage(new CultureInfo("en")) + "!");
```

can all be subject to the same, unchanged test which verifies the expected string is printed to the console.

Replacing a console output by some GUI output, however, is a change which obviously changes the externally visible behaviour, hence there is no reason to assume tests don't have to be changed.

<sub>Side note: how to implement a test which verifies that a certain message box with a certain text will be shown, and if it is justified call such a test a "unit test" is a separate topic which I don't discuss here.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

> I have read that the changes to the code base should not change the unit tests.

The answer is that it depends.

If the change to the code base occurred early in the development process such that the code failed unit testing prior to the change, then no, you don't change your unit tests to make that failure a success. You change the code to make it pass the already written unit tests.

There are however occasions where changes to the code base do require changes to the unit tests. Unit tests are code, and like any other code, they can be buggy. If during the course of development, it is a unit test that turns out to be buggy, change that unit test. Do not reimplement the bug in the code base such that that the code base passes the buggy unit test.

Other occasions where a change to the unit tests is needed is when the code base change occurred during maintenance. Perhaps some external user reported what they think is a bug and the maintenance team concurs that it is a bug. Ideally, this bug should have been caught by unit testing prior to release. Changes to both the code base and to the unit tests are in order. Or perhaps external users requested a new feature, management concurred, and a prototype modification appears to be working. Once again, changes to both the code base and to the unit tests are in order.

Answer (score 0):

> I have read that the changes to the code base should not change the
> unit tests.

This 100000% makes sense and is critical to good unit testing.

The key thing, which I think you realise, is that the unit test should test the desired behaviour, which you don't expected to change regardless of implementation.

The goal of this rule is try and stop people writing unit tests which test the detail of implementations rather than the overall results of operations.

Your example is a good one in that both implementations hide what they do, one writes to console and one to messagebox, but they do it as a non-exposed, internal to the class thing. This type of thing would normally be considered part of the implementation, but in your case writing out the message is also the desired behaviour.

How do you follow the unit testing rule about not testing internal behaviour/implementation details whilst also testing the desired behaviour of writing messages? You have to change the class to make unit testing possible.

so for example you could inject the output writer

```
public interface IGreetingService
{
    void ShowGreeting();
}

public class GreetingService : IGreetingService
{
    IStreamWriter ouput
    public GreetingService(IStreamWriter ouput) { this.output = output }
    public void ShowGreeting()
    {
        ouput.WriteLine("Hello!");
    }
}
```

Now I can inject the message box or the console as required and the behaviour of the class is to write "Hello!" to the stream that is passed in. Which makes your unit test better.

```
TestGreeting()
{
    var testOutput = new Mock<IStreamWriter>();
    var target = new GreetingService(testOutput);
    target.ShowGreeting();
    var actual = testOutput.ReadLine();
    Assert(actual = "Hello!");
}
```

Now your unit test test the desired behaviour and won't change with the implementation. Because of the way you have defined "desired behaviour" and "implementation" for your class.

By following the rule you have been forced to change the design of your codebase. This is the intent of the rule, not to say that you will never have to rewrite your tests, but to try make you design your code in a such a way that your *requirements* are testable.

**Also!** there is an common anti pattern where people deliberately tests the internals of their classes and miss the real requirements. The rule tries to steer you away from doing this.

eg.

```
string Translate(string in)
{
   var out = "";
   var words = this.splitIntoWords(in);
   foreach(var w in words)
   {
      t = this.translate(w);
      out += w + " ";
   }
   return out
}

TranslateTest
{
   var t = new Translator();
   var out = t.Translate("hello world");
   Assert(t.splitIntoWords("hello world").WasCalled());
   Assert(t.translate("hello").WasCalled());
   Assert(t.translate("world").WasCalled());
}
```

Here our class is fully tested, however the actual requirements are not. It's not required that you split the string, or translate each word individually, that's just how you have chosen to implement the translation. The test will break if you change the implementation, even if the result is the same. Which we call "brittle", and in fact this test doesn't test the *real* requirement of was a correct translation returned.

Comment: This is a great answer. I would guess the downvoter stopped reading at the 100000% and didn’t read the rest which explained that it’s correct for behavior. Might want to make that “For behavior that is 100000%”.

Comment: thanks, yeah it's basically the same as docs answer in detail but they miss the point that rules like this are supposed to be simple all encompassing rules. If you start adding "..for behaviour" or "when test are written this way.." then you end up with a page of guidelines instead of a simple rule which forces you to do things a certain way, even if it doesn't catch every edgecase

Comment: I disagree with this 10000000%. (I added a few zeros there.) Suppose the code change exposes a bug in the test code and everyone agrees that the bug is in the test code rather than the code base. Do you change the code so that it properly passes the buggy unit test, or do you change the unit test? Or suppose an external user has reported a bug or asked for a new feature,  submits a proposed code change that fixes the bug / implements the feature, but does not change the test code. Everyone likes the change as-is, so the change to the code base is easy. You need a new unit test in this case.

Comment: @DavidHammen: unless you are doing bug-for-bug rewrite or some similar situation where changes are disallowed, you find a bug, you fix it.  Doesn’t matter whether the bug is in the app, the test or the docs.

Comment: @jmoreno Except in the case where the unit test authors were taken from the top 100000% of the organization's programmers and were 100000% prescient, they were merely human and were prone to make mistakes. A bug in some unit test is a bug, period. A bug is a bug, period. You don't "fix" the code to replicate the bug in the buggy test. You fix the buggy test that caused the non-buggy code base to fail.

Comment: @DavidHammen: which is what I said. There are occasionally reasons to keep bugs in the code, no reason ever to keep bugs in tests.

Comment: Maybe there is a misunderstanding here. My critics goes against this general statement "changes to the code base". It seems you read this as "changes to implementations of certain behaviour" (and we both agree that this should not be a reason to change a test). But fact is, the OP seems to missed that "changes to the code base" means something different than "changes to implementations of certain behaviour", and that looks to me like the root cause of their confusion.

Comment: I think you guys are being overly prescriptive in your interpretations. Let me ask this "should" you be able to change the "codebase" without _having_ to change the tests?

Comment: if you agree that with well written code this should be possible, then you agree with the rule as phrased

Comment: @DavidHammen im not saying "never change tests under any circumstances" im saying write your code in a way which enables you to change it without _requiring_ a change in the tests. Which im 100000000000.9999% sure is what the referenced book means

Comment: @Ewan: why should arbitrary changes to a codebase (including all kind of changes to public functions and features) be possible without changing any tests? This makes no sense to me.

Comment: @DocBrown i'm pretty sure you do understand the principle, that's why you've added the word "arbitrary" to the rule.  There is no such thing as an arbitrary change, you make a change to match the specifications and the tests test that the specifications are matched. They only change when you change the specifications. Now sure, you can refactor, or fix a bug and have to change an interface or whatever, but the rule is very normal and im sure you have seen it before in various forms